# EF4 - Foreach local variable with static data

Tags: entity-framework, view, foreach

I'm using EF4. I've found a very annoying issue.

I have a db view that I've dragged into my Entity Model class.
When I try to iterate over the hole collection, the data displayed, it's almost the same that the first objects... I've tried enabling Lazy Loading, but nothing works.. it's a really simple snippet.. why doesn't work???

```
Dal.Entities context = new Dal.Entities();                
list = context.vw_Full_Poll.ToList();

foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    PrintPoll(htmlWriter, item);
                }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what the problem is. Can you rephrase the question better? What do you mean by "almost the same that the first objects"? You say "nothing works", what do you mean by that? Can you explain what you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't [defined a PK for the view](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx). Since DB VIEWs don't have PKs, the EF can't derive this automatically.

Comment: By "almost the same that the first objects" I meant that for example, the hole data contains about 5000 rows, and when I printed these rows, the data displayed is the same for the row #1,#2,#3...

Comment: When I said, nothing works, I meant that by enabling Lazy Loading, the result is the same... the printed data corresponds to the #1-#10 rows printed many times as rows returned the DAO method.

Comment: Ok!!! worked!! Thanks! It's a little strange cause using old "ADO disconnected mode", foreach funcionality worked just fine... but also, makes sense, that EF possibily isn't able to find which record is different from another without a PK. Thanks again